# Focus next textview automatically

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` with `android:maxLength` set to `3` and another with `android:maxLength` set to `7`.

I want focus to automatically move to the second `TextView` once the `3` chars of the first `TextView` are filled up. How to achieve this without inheriting `TextView` and writing a custom implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tried but this might work.

Setup a listener to fire when the text was changed, for this use

```
addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher)
```

Then based on the text length you can request the focus change to the next field.

If you want to find out the next field you can call `View.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_FORWARD)` Find the nearest view in the specified direction that can take focus. This does not actually give focus to that view.

Comment: I did this - 

 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
 if (s.length() == 3) {
 
 Log.d(TAG,"Next focus is at:  "+tv1.getNextFocusDownId());
 tv1.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
 }





But it did not work - what am I doing wrong ?
The Log prints the message correctly when length is 3, but the focus does not shift automatically to the next view.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment - tv2.requestFocus() worked.

Thanks !

Comment: View.FOCUS_FORWARD isn't a permitted value for View.focusSearch. only real directions.

Answer (score 5):

For future readers expecting to `COPY/PASTE`

```
int MAX_LENGTH = 3;

txt1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.length() == MAX_LENGTH) {
            txt2.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```