# Android EditText AutoFocus to next EditText when at maxlength

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have a username and a password XML segment

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:hint="@string/username_hint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:maxLength="9"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/pswd"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
<EditText 
    android:inputType="textPassword" 
    android:hint="@string/password_hint"
    android:id="@+id/pswd" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
```

I want when the username field reaches the 9th character for the cursor focus to automatically jump to the password field

I was looking at [Focus next textview automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943159/focus-next-textview-automatically) and was trying:

```
final EditText usr = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.username);
final EditText pswd = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.pswd);
usr.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
        if (s.length() == 9) { 
            pswd.requestFocus(); 
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
    int count, int after) {
    }
});
```

To not much success. I am using this in my `oncreate` method in which I am processing my login information. Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try this code?

Answer (score 1):

try like this may help you.

/** addTextChangedListener is useful when first username box is filled with reaches the 9th character 
         * the request will automatically focus to next box*/

```
usr.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
         if (count == 9) { 
             pwd.requestFocus(); 
             usr.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
         }
    }
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
   }
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
           int count, int after) {
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Print out your `"s"` with `log.d()` or something, so you can see how `"s"` looks like. 
Maybe its not how you expect.
In this case you can `code it dirty`.
 Make your own `TextWatcher` that *implements TextWatcher* and give in the Constructor the `"usr"`. 
so you can get the total length with `usr.getText()`

Answer (score 0):

hello i have try right now ,but i success ,our code are same, my xml is simple only two editText my phone is Meizu version is 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this on the afterTextChanged method.
also you can call usr.clearFocus() before requesting the focus on pwd.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `nextfocusdown` from your edit text xml.

```
final EditText usr = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.username);

final EditText pswd = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.pswd);

usr.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
{

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
    { 

        if (usr.getText.toString().length() == 9) (Use usr.getText.toString() instead of s) 
        { 
            pswd.requestFocus(); 
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
        int count, int after) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

usr
.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{

```
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
            { 
                String tusr = usr.getText().toString();
                if (tusr.length()==2) //max lenght 2bit
                { 
                    pswd.requestFocus(); 
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }
        });
```